# How to run multiple Jmeter scenarios i.e. .jmx files in Jenkins one by one?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, performance-testing, django-jenkins

I have successfully created some Jmeter scenarios for performance testing, now i want to run those scenarios one after another without any failure.

As per some search, i found Jenkins would be suitable for this.

Can you tell me how i can run all Jmeter scenarios in Jenkins.

**Work done and work to achieve:** I have created one item in Jenkins which runs one single scenario. Like wise if i create different items i would be able to run all scenarios.

**Question:** **Is there is any method or plugin by which i can integrate all items in Jenkins so that they can run one after another.**

**Condition:** Also consider the case where (say) out of 10 scenario 5 ran one after another and 6th stuck somewhere , i would be able to run next scenarios too (i.e. 7,8,9 10).

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve expected functionality use Jenkins [multiJob plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin), or pipline your jobs in Jenkins. Check this [article](http://www.methodsandtools.com/archive/archive.php?id=121). I both situations you can define case when to build "downstream" jobs.